# Выравнивание div'ов относительно друг друга

Tags: html, css

Приветствую всех вошедших. (Ухожу от таблиц)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style>
        #top    {width:500;height:100;background-color:#CC0000;display:block;}

        #cen    {width:100;height:100;background-color:#00CC00;display:inline-block;}
        #cem    {width:300;height:100;background-color:#0000CC;display:inline-block;}
        #cet    {width:100;height:100;background-color:#00CC00;display:inline-block;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="cen"></div><div id="cem"></div><div id="cet"></div>
    </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Вот простая web страница. Можно часть кода написать так:

```
<div id="cen"></div>
<div id="cem"></div>
<div id="cet"></div>
```

1 Появляются пробелы между div'ами. Можно ли как то избежать этих пробелов?
 - можно конечно писать в строчку - но не удобно, т.к. div'ы бывают большими
 - можно приравнять каждый div к переменной на PHP, и все же в строчку - но это изврат
 - можно обнулить CSS - но не сработает
 - еще можно сделать все на таблицах - но от таблиц как раз пытаюсь перейти на div'ы.

2 Можно ли как то избавиться от тега <center>?
 - вычитал на хэшкоде, что можно в боди добавить margin:auto - не сработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// css
    <style>
    .one    { width:1000px; min-height:10px; border:0px solid blue; background-color:#0000CC; display:block; margin: 0 auto; }
    .two    { width:1000px; height:50px; background-color:#00CC00; display:block;}
    .try    { width:0200px; height:50px; background-color:#CC0000; display:inline-block;}
    .che    { width:0800px; height:50px; background-color:#CCCC00; display:inline-block;}
    </style>

// html
<div class="one">
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="try"></div><!--
    --><div class="che"></div>
</div>
```

1 - обычно делают 1 див, который выровнен по центру, а внутри него остальные. Если нужно несколько - делай несколько, они все должны быть дисплей блок, а уже в нутри них все извращения

2 - сам не знаток CSS, проблемы с пробелами между дивами - у себя решил извращениями, обрати внимание на <!-- и --> (с хэшкода где то вытащил). Буду рад, если кто подскажет, что посерьезнее

Answer (score 0):

1. Попробуйте использовать вместо inline-block просто block
2. Выравнить блок по центру не margin: auto , a "margin: 0 auto;"

Comment: 1. если так сделать - блоки будут один под другим, а не в одну строку

2. если прописать это в body, или обернуть все в еще один div - все равно выравнивание идет по левому краю